# How to output quotation marks correctly with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to write a node.js file to auto-generate some HTML code, and I'm having some trouble with my quotation marks. I tried the escape character, and mixing double and single quotes, but all it's outputting is a bunch of double quotes, and none of the text in my output. How can I get this to work? This is my code, which I'm running at localhost:8080:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var i;
    var br = "\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= 227; i++) {
        res.write( br + '<div id="jd' + i + '" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>' + br);
    }
    res.end("");

}).listen(8080);
```

This should be outputting 227 lines such as

```
<div id="jd1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: You have a stray `"` at the very end of the line, after `</div>`.

Comment: @ChrisG Getting rid of that just makes it so nothing at all shows up. I edited it out of the question.

Comment: Might want to do some research into [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @TimGraupner Nothing at all shows up, correct. The browser is rendering 227 empty divs, which means you will only see them in the source view. Are you asking how to display HTML code in the browser window? In that case you can add this `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");` at the start of the function.

Comment: Try adding a header and getting rid of the br variable. response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"}); for (i = 1; i <= 227; i++) {
        res.write( '<div id="jd' + i + '" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>');
    }
    res.end(); And as @ChrisG mentioned, check the source, or put some test text between the div tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written works perfectly. To see the rendered div you can add some text inside div so it will visible on browser window.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var i;
    var br = "\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= 227; i++) {
        res.write( br + '<div id="jd' + i + '" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>' + br);
    }
    res.end("");

}).listen(3000);
```

**Output:**  Empty divs - See screenshot 
[image]

Try with plain text -

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var i;
    var br = "\n";
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    for (i = 1; i <= 227; i++) {
        res.write( br + '<div id="jd' + i + '" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>' + br);
    }
    res.end("");

}).listen(3000);
```

**Output** Plain text
[image]